# Not Showing Image In GridView

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

It showing image path  in database but not showing image in `gridview`

```
FileUpload2.SaveAs(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "./img/" + FileUpload2.FileName.ToString());
            b = "img/" + FileUpload2.FileName.ToString();
```

this code I write for image

Comment: how you tried to display image? in gridview...if you used any image tag or imagebutton than show the code for that which you used

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="230px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("product_image") %>' Width="350px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>

Comment: this code i use

Comment: and have you tried using inspect element to check what you are getting in image url

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Image id="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/{0}",Eval("ProductImage"))%>' height="150" width="150" />
```

Try this code. It worked for me

Comment: ohk sir.. just now i show my path in dabase it taking to image to another folder which is not present in my  project it take to another folder.. it created new folder there it pass data

Comment: you are storing absolute path or relative path in database?

Comment: should i send u screen of that ?

Comment: hello i got my fault and now it working properly.. thank you so much for your all contribute.. keep helping me whenever i stuck in my cod

Comment: That’s great. 